# apply script to all elements

Tags: jquery

i need to show all images, which are in the `div` with `class="deep"`.

when i try the following script it doesn't work.

`$(".deep img").css("visibility", "visible");`

i can solve the problem using something like `.each`, but maybe there is something more simple?

Thanks

Comment: This works for me. There is probably something else wrong.

Comment: is your markup valid? paste the source to w3c validator http://validator.w3.org/. jQuery needs a valid dom to work good

Comment: sorry, i have another wrong part in my script, it works **fine** ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are `visibility: hidden` this will work.  However, more often they're `display:none`, in which case do this:

```
$(".deep img").show();
```

Comment: yes, they has `visibility: hidden` before script, but by so it doesn't work. i have many div's with `class="deep"`, and i need to apply to all images in all divs with `deep` class

Comment: @Syom - It will still work, jQuery executes the chain against *all* elements the selector matched, not just the first.  There must be something else going on if your current code isn't doing this.

Answer (score 0):

What is the state of the images before you attempt the above line? Are they display:none?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
$('.deep').find('img').css("visibility", "visible");

Comment: That is what he has

$('.deep img') is the same as $('.deep').find('img')